# any website that show decoded mainnet transaction trace?

Tags: trace

I remember I saw such site when I first start learning about smart contracts last month. It is better than etherscan.io's parity trace, called function name and input are also decoded.

anyone know such site? I remember the one I opened was in black theme.

Comment: Do you mean ethtx.info?

Comment: thank you. this looks like a good alternative